# Cannot find the file specified when trying to run cordova app on blackberry emulator

Tags: blackberry, cordova, blackberry-10, cordova-3

I'm putting together a blackberry10 app using cordova for the first time.

I'm starting with the hello world example to get me going but am not able to get the app running in my emulator.

When I run

`cordova emulate blackberry10`

I get the following error:

`Generating config.xml from defaults for platform "blackberry10"
Preparing blackberry10 project Running on emulator for platform "blackberry10" via command "cmd" /c D:\Workspac
es\AppWorkspace\hello\platforms\blackberry10\cordova\run --emulator
[Error: An error occurred while emulating/deploying the blackberry10 project. The system cannot find the file specified.
]`

I'm sure I've set everything up correctly though. I'm on cordova 3.1 on windows 7 and have done the following:

- Installed the SDK and added to my path: C:\bbndk\host_10_2_0_15\win32\x86\usr\bin
- Requested and installed the signing files
- Created the hello world project using the normal steps

cordova create hello com.example.hello
cd hello
cordova platform add blackberry10
cordova build

- Installed and started the emulator, with developer mode enabled
- Run `platforms\blackberry10\cordova\target.bat add emu 169.254.0.1 -t simulator`

The target.bat also gives me "The system cannot find the file specified" error.

If anyone has a work around or suggestion that would be great.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When running the command "cordova build -d" I managed to find an error which was linking to image files that are not there. It seems that the config file within the www gets altered by the build command and adds paths to non existent image files.

I haven't tinkered with it yet but for now I have simply added the files with the same names within the blackberry10 config file and the project now builds and runs on the simulator just fine.

Change blackberry folder with res icons and screens to blackberry10.
Within screens add images with the following names splash-1280x768.pnp, splash-720x720.png ,splash-768x1280.png

Change the name of windows phone icon icon-173 to icon-173-tile within the config file in your www folder.